# How to set Location of another Control proportionally

Tags: c#, winforms, point

My problem is : I have 2 Panels (panel1,panel2) where `panel1.Size = new Size(200, 200);` and `Panel2.Size = new Size(600, 600);` where both panel's have within a CustomControl which can get Dragged and change it Possition (szbControl1 ,szbControl2) .

My Question is ,how can i set `szbControl2.Location` properly (proportionally)based on `szbControl1.Location` where `szbControl1` parent is `panel1` and `szbControl2` parent is `panel2` ,like if i move the `szbControl1` at bottom also `szbControl2` should be at bottom.
So far i tried this :

```
private void sizeAbleCTR2_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int smallX = (sizeAbleCTR2.Location.X * panel1.Size.Width) / 100;
            int smallY = (sizeAbleCTR2.Location.Y * panel1.Size.Height) / 100;

            int largeX = (smallX * panel2.Width) / 100;
            int largeY = (smallY * panel2.Height) / 100;

            sizeAbleCTR1.Location = new Point(largeX,largeY);
        }
```

like using the Percentage but it's not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided does not take into account the size of the szbControls. The ratio of the (location/the differences of the sizes) should be equal.

```
private void sizeAbleCTR2_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float srcHeightDiff = panel2.Height - sizeAbleCTR2.Height;
    float dstHeightDiff = panel1.Height - sizeAbleCTR1.Height;

    int locY = (int)(dstHeightDiff * (sizeAbleCTR2.Location.Y / srcHeightDiff));

    float srcWidthDiff = panel2.Width - sizeAbleCTR2.Width;
    float dstWidthDiff = panel1.Width - sizeAbleCTR1.Width;

    int locX = (float)(dstWidthDiff * (sizeAbleCTR2.Location.X / srcWidthDiff));

    sizeAbleCTR1.Location = new Point(locX, locY);
}
```